# How to parse fixed free text using R

Tags: r, parsing, nlp, tidyverse

I have the following free text:

```
#################################################################
# If you used AutoDock Vina in your work, please cite:          #
#                                                               #
# O. Trott, A. J. Olson,                                        #
# AutoDock Vina: improving the speed and accuracy of docking    #
# with a new scoring function, efficient optimization and       #
# multithreading, Journal of Computational Chemistry 31 (2010)  #
# 455-461                                                       #
#                                                               #
# DOI 10.1002/jcc.21334                                         #
#                                                               #
# Please see http://vina.scripps.edu for more information.      #
#################################################################

WARNING: The search space volume > 27000 Angstrom^3 (See FAQ)
Detected 8 CPUs
Reading input ... done.
Setting up the scoring function ... done.
Analyzing the binding site ... done.
Using random seed: -1553787135
Performing search ... done.
Refining results ... done.

mode |   affinity | dist from best mode
     | (kcal/mol) | rmsd l.b.| rmsd u.b.
-----+------------+----------+----------
   1         -5.9      0.000      0.000
   2         -5.7     22.945     25.492
   3         -5.5      1.426      2.046
   4         -5.5     23.669     25.616
   5         -5.4     25.783     29.152
   6         -5.3     21.146     23.357
   7         -5.2     20.323     22.545
   8         -5.2     23.864     26.064
   9         -5.1     23.422     26.585
Writing output ... done.
```

The text is fixed only the value under the table above changed.
What I want to do is to extract the table and keep it as a data frame.

```
mode |   affinity | dist from best mode
     | (kcal/mol) | rmsd l.b.| rmsd u.b.
-----+------------+----------+----------
   1         -5.9      0.000      0.000
   2         -5.7     22.945     25.492
   3         -5.5      1.426      2.046
   4         -5.5     23.669     25.616
   5         -5.4     25.783     29.152
   6         -5.3     21.146     23.357
   7         -5.2     20.323     22.545
   8         -5.2     23.864     26.064
   9         -5.1     23.422     26.585
```

I have hundreds of such files which I need to parse.
Is there a way or package in R that can do that?

Comment: do all files have the same header and footer (above and below the 'real' data)?

Comment: @Wimpel yes. Even the number of rows in real data always fixed -> 9.

Answer (score 2):

consider this testfile `testfile1.txt` in the subdirectory `./data`

[image]

```
# Create a list of files to parse
files.to.read <- list.files("./data", pattern = "^testfile.\\.txt$", full.names = TRUE)
library(data.table)
# Read the files using data.table::fread()
#   Skip the first 26 rows (incl the col-headers)
#   Read only 9 lines
#   set the column headers manually
L <- lapply( files.to.read, fread, nrows = 9, skip = 26, 
             col.names = c("mode", "affinity", "rmsd_lb", "rmsd_ub"))
# Set the names of list L to  originating txt-files (if needed)
names(L) <- basename(files.to.read)
# Rowbind all read in data to one large data.table, keep originating filename
DT <- rbindlist(L, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE, idcol = "origin")
#           origin mode affinity rmsd_lb rmsd_ub
# 1: testfile1.txt    1     -5.9   0.000   0.000
# 2: testfile1.txt    2     -5.7  22.945  25.492
# 3: testfile1.txt    3     -5.5   1.426   2.046
# 4: testfile1.txt    4     -5.5  23.669  25.616
# 5: testfile1.txt    5     -5.4  25.783  29.152
# 6: testfile1.txt    6     -5.3  21.146  23.357
# 7: testfile1.txt    7     -5.2  20.323  22.545
# 8: testfile1.txt    8     -5.2  23.864  26.064
# 9: testfile1.txt    9     -5.1  23.422  26.585
```